# Stored Procedure is not called when send request along with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.NET MVC application in C# where I am calling a stored procedure `CreateFunctionNavigation`. I am having issue calling that stored procedure along with parameters. I have model class as;

`Model` class

```
public class CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map
{
    public CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map()
    {
    }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Function Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Title")]
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Function Hierarchy; i.e Where Function Exists In Hierarchy Tree \n Top-Level Start From 1 ")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Hierarchy Level")]
    public int FunctionHierarchy_Level { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Controller Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Controller Title")]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Action Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Action Title")]
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Function Parent - Child Relation ID \n Put 0 In Case Given Function doesn't Have Any Parent Function ")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Parent's FunctionID")]
    public int Function_ParentsFunctionID { get; set; }     
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFunctionNavigation] 
 @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
 @Hierarchy_Level INT,
 @Function_identity INT OUTPUT, 
 @ControllerName nvarchar(250), 
 @Controller_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @ControllerInFunction_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @ActionName nvarchar(250),
 @Action_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @ActionInFunction_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @Function_ParentsFunctionID INT,
 @Function_ParentsFunction_identity INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_Functions] ([FunctionName],[Hierarchy_Level]) 
  VALUES(@FunctionName, @Hierarchy_Level)

  SET @Function_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_FunctionController] ([ControllerName])
  VALUES(@ControllerName)

  SET @Controller_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_FunctionInController] ([Function_ID], [ControllerID])
  VALUES (@Function_identity, @Controller_identity)

  SET @ControllerInFunction_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_FunctionAction] ([ActionName], [ControllerID])
  VALUES (@ActionName, @Controller_identity)

  SET @Action_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_FunctionInAction] ([ActionID], [Function_ID])
  VALUES (@Action_identity, @Function_identity)

  SET @ActionInFunction_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Navigation_FunctionHierarchy] ([Function_IDs], [Parent_Function_ID])
  VALUES (@Function_identity, @Function_ParentsFunctionID)

  SET @Function_ParentsFunction_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  RETURN
END
```

now in C# class I am trying to run this stored procedure with passing parameters but in SQL Server Profiler I cannot see if this stored procedure is not called.

C# Code to run stored procedure

```
 var _result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map>("exec CreateFunctionNavigation @FunctionName @FunctionHierarchy_Level @ControllerName @ActionName @Function_ParentsFunctionID", 
                 new SqlParameter("FunctionName",_entity.FunctionName),
                 new SqlParameter("FunctionHierarchy_Level",_entity.FunctionHierarchy_Level),
                 new SqlParameter("ControllerName", _entity.ControllerName),
                 new SqlParameter("ActionName", _entity.ActionName),
                 new SqlParameter("Function_ParentsFunctionID",_entity.Function_ParentsFunctionID)

                 );
```

But if I run this stored procedure by just calling it without parameter and of course simply stored procedure with select statement then it works and I can also see in SQL Profiler that stored procedure is called.

Working C# code

```
List<CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map> query;
query = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map>("exec CreateFunctionNavigation").ToList();
```

So I believe issue is C# class from where I am trying to call SP along with parameters. I badly stuck, tried different options but don't know what I am doing wrong. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer; it is working

```
 List<GetNewlyCreatedNavigationsFunction_SP_Map> _query;

             var function_identity_out = new SqlParameter("Function_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
             var controller_identity_out = new SqlParameter("Controller_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
             var controllerInFunction_identity_out = new SqlParameter("ControllerInFunction_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
             var action_identity_out = new SqlParameter("Action_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
             var actionInFunction_identity_out = new SqlParameter("ActionInFunction_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
             var function_ParentsFunction_identity_out = new SqlParameter("Function_ParentsFunction_identity", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };


             _query = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<GetNewlyCreatedNavigationsFunction_SP_Map>("exec CreateFunctionNavigation @FunctionName, @Hierarchy_Level, @ControllerName, @ActionName, @Function_ParentsFunctionID, @Function_identity out, @Controller_identity out, @ControllerInFunction_identity out, @Action_identity out, @ActionInFunction_identity out, @Function_ParentsFunction_identity out",
                new SqlParameter("@FunctionName", _entity.FunctionName),
                new SqlParameter("@Hierarchy_Level", _entity.FunctionHierarchy_Level),
                new SqlParameter("@ControllerName", _entity.ControllerName),
                new SqlParameter("@ActionName", _entity.ActionName),
                new SqlParameter("@Function_ParentsFunctionID", _entity.Function_ParentsFunctionID),
                function_identity_out,
                controller_identity_out,
                controllerInFunction_identity_out,
                action_identity_out,
                actionInFunction_identity_out,
                function_ParentsFunction_identity_out 
              ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding commas inbetween your parameter names?

```
dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map>("exec CreateFunctionNavigation @FunctionName, @FunctionHierarchy_Level, @ControllerName, @ActionName, @Function_ParentsFunctionID"
```

UPDATE: just checked out your stored proc code too, seen there are some issues with it.

Here is how I would change it

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFunctionNavigation] 
 @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
 @Hierarchy_Level INT,    
 @ControllerName nvarchar(250), 
 @ActionName nvarchar(250),
 @Function_ParentsFunctionID INT,
 @Function_identity INT OUTPUT, 
 @Controller_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @ControllerInFunction_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @Action_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @ActionInFunction_identity INT OUTPUT,
 @Function_ParentsFunction_identity INT OUTPUT
```

This puts all your outputs at the end of the function.

Right, on your c# code

```
var function_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "Function_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
var controller_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "Controller_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
var controllerInFunction_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "ControllerInFunction_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
var action_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "Action_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
var actionInFunction_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "ActionInFunction_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};
var function_ParentsFunction_identity new SqlParameter() {ParameterName = "Function_ParentsFunction_identity", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output};

var _result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CreateFunctionNavigation_SP_Map>("exec CreateFunctionNavigation @FunctionName, @FunctionHierarchy_Level, @ControllerName, @ActionName, @Function_ParentsFunctionID, @Function_identity out, @Controller_identity out, @ControllerInFunction_identity out, @Action_identity out, @ActionInFunction_identity out, @Function_ParentsFunction_identity out", 
             new SqlParameter("FunctionName",_entity.FunctionName),
             new SqlParameter("FunctionHierarchy_Level",_entity.FunctionHierarchy_Level),
             new SqlParameter("ControllerName", _entity.ControllerName),
             new SqlParameter("ActionName", _entity.ActionName),
             new SqlParameter("Function_ParentsFunctionID",_entity.Function_ParentsFunctionID),
function_identity ,
controller_identity ,
controllerInFunction_identity ,
action_identity ,
actionInFunction_identity,
function_ParentsFunction_identity 

             );
```

That might get you somewhere close.

Comment: even with comma, there is no result

Comment: many thanks for guidance, I have managed to solve this issue, code is in my answer above